# index error with lists while using del, cant figure it out

Tags: python

I am new to programming so this code is probable fairly junky. Anyhow what i am trying to do is take two lists(xy1,xy2), which hold the corners of a rectangle and see if they overlap with other rectangles. The format i used for it is x1,y1 are in array xy1 and x2,y2 are in array xy2. So far i am only working with the x axis so every other entry in both of the arrays. My problem is that when i find the ones that are overlapping and delete them i get an index error. I believe the problem is something to do with using del and my for loops max which i get using the len of the array. The code also works sometimes if nothing overlaps and triggers the removed calls. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

```
#1,3 are x cords for first rect, 5 and 8 are x cords for second rect
xy1=[1,6,5,12,1,17]
xy2=[3,9,8,16,4,19]
def make(xy1,xy2):
    count0=0
    for count1 in range(count0,len(xy1),2):
        for count2 in range(count0,len(xy2),2):
            if xy1[count1] in range(xy1[count2],xy2[count2]) and not (count1==count2):
                xy1=removed(xy1,count1)
                xy2=removed(xy2,count1)
    return xy1,xy2

def removed(xy1,count1):
    #removes the x,y that was overlapped along with the other 2 corners of the rect
    del xy1[count1:count1+2]
    return xy1

make(xy1,xy2)

print xy1,xy2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like TJD said you have an array that is shrinking so you will get an index out of range error.

Without changing your code much, you can solve this by going through the list backwards. If you change the first three lines of your procedure, you should get the result you want and no longer get an error.

```
def make(xy1,xy2):
count0=-1
for count1 in range(len(xy1)-2,count0,-2):
    for count2 in range(len(xy2)-2,count0,-2):
        if xy1[count1] in range(xy1[count2],xy2[count2]) and not (count1==count2):
            xy1=removed(xy1,count1)
            xy2=removed(xy2,count1)
return xy1,xy2
```

Comment: Thanks for that. never really knew you could reverse the for loops, but it works great, that is going to be quite useful in many situations thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that every time you delete something, the length of your array xy1 is shrinking.  But your count iterators keep increasing without taking that into account.  You could see the behavior more clearly if you print `xy1` and `count1` each time right before you do `del`